# Navigate from notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation, notifications, toast

I made scheduled task agent. It work ok but I don't know how to recognize if user open an application by toast notification or by normal click on tile.

Or maybe you know just how to open different page just by click in notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
string launchString = args.Arguments
    If (  launchString ….)
    {
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(page2));
    }
    else
    {
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
...
}
```

Comment: In toast notification you can set launch attribute. And process the attribute in OnLaunched.

Comment: I am using ShellToast in ScheduledAget.cs and there aren't any set attribute

Comment: You can use NavigateUri property in ShellToast if send notification only from ScheduledAget.cs.  Then process the NavigateUri and make navigation to the desired page. Everything is described in the MSDN library.
Study carefully. For example this link [Toasts for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: I did like you said in shellToast I set navigationuri like NavigationUri = new Uri("/View/SettingsPage.xaml?value1=quicktest &amp;value2=9876", UriKind.Absolute), and on MainPage protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   
                string strVal1 = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["value1"];

but those queryString is empty @user2784555

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly-you need to open the application when the user clicked on the toast notification.

Here are all described in detail:
[How to handle activation from a toast notification (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx)

Comment: If I click on toast notification I want to open page2.xaml not MainPage.xaml

Comment: I would have tried to handle the argument to the event handler OnLaunched.

Comment: you mean in Application_Launching I will see by what application was open?